# Why count of empty string("") return count 1 greater then the length of target string?

Tags: python

How following statements are working?

```
In [91]: stars
Out[91]: '******'

In [92]: stars.count("")   #<<<<
Out[92]: 7

In [94]: stars.replace("", "V")   #<<<
Out[94]: 'V*V*V*V*V*V*V'
```

Comment: It looks pretty clear to me. Python considers between each character, and at the start and end of the string, to be an instance of `""`. This is clearly visible where you replace each one with `"V"`.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill do you have a link where this point is mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

While it may seem counter-intuitive... there's effectively an empty string before each character in the string and one at the end.

Comment: Whoa! What happened to the other puppy?

Comment: @Ashwini I've taken up ninjitsu? :p